# Show that $L$ and $\overline L$ cannot be both finite

Tags: formal-languages

> Let $L$ be any language on a nonempty alphabet. Show that $L$ and $\overline L$ cannot be both finite.

This is exercise 7 (page 28) from "An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata" by Peter Linz.

My attempt: $L$ is a subset of $\Sigma^*$, so it can be either finite or infinite. If $L$ is finite, then $\overline L$ is infinite. If $L$ is infinite, that is, $L = \Sigma^*$, then $\overline L = \Sigma^* - L = \Sigma^* - \Sigma^* = \emptyset$. Therefore, $L$ and $\overline L$ cannot be both finite.

Is it correct? I tried to write a direct proof. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/what-to-do-when-the-answer-is-already-part-of-the-question. If you have a doubt about a specific part of the solution, please specify it. Anyway, "If $L$ is infinite, that is, $L = \Sigma^*$" is not correct. I would also explain why "If $L$ is finite then $\bar L$ is infinite".

Answer (score 1):

If $L$ and $\overline{L}$ were both finite, then so would $\Sigma^* = L \cup \overline{L}$ be, which we know is false.

This is a qualitative statement. We can make it quantitative by considering densities. Let us say that a language is *dense* if for infinitely many $n$, it contains at least half the words of length $n$. It is easy to check that at least one of $L,\overline{L}$ is dense.

Answer (score -1):

Your **intuition** is correct, however I wouldn't call it a "formal" proof. A *really* formal proof (but seriously, its *too* formal) can be stated like that:

If $L$ is infinite, we are done. Otherwise, $|L|<\infty$. In particular, there is some $w\in L$ such that $|w|\ge |w'|$ for every other $w'\in L$ - that is, $w$ is the longest in $L$. Denote $n:=|w|$, and notice that $\{w'\in \Sigma^*\mid |w'|>n\} \subseteq \Sigma^* \setminus L = \bar L$. Define $f:\Sigma^*\rightarrow \{w'\in \Sigma^*\mid |w'|>n\}$ by $f(w)=0^{n+1}w$ (instead of $0$, you can choose some other letter from $\Sigma$). Clearly, $f$ is injective, and therefore $|\Sigma^*|\le |\{w'\in \Sigma^*\mid |w'|>n\}|\le |\bar L|$. Since $\Sigma^*$ is infinite, then $\bar L$ is infinite as well, just as required.

Once again, this is a formal solution to the question. Your solution is still definitely valid, but note that $L$ being infinite **does not automatically imply** that $L=\Sigma^*$ (Thanks Dmitry for pointing this out in the comments).

Comment: Sounds like an overkill. You can simply say that if both $|L|, |\bar L| < \infty$, then $|\Sigma^*| = |L \cup \bar L| = |L| + |\bar L| < \infty$ - contradiction with infinity of $\Sigma^*$.

Comment: You are right. This can be solved way more simply.

Comment: Feel free to post it as a separate answer. I will definitely upvote it :)

Comment: Sorry, it's my policy to not post answers which perfectly fit in comments:)

Comment: What about "If $L$ is infinite, then $\overline L$ is either a nonempty finite set or an empty set"? Is it valid?

Comment: No, for example, if $\bar L$ would have been all words with even length, then $L$ would be all words with odd length. Clearly, $\bar L$ is infinite, but $L$ is not empty and not even finite.

Comment: @Dmitry The network-wide policy is to not post answers in the comments. You lose out on reputation, the asker can't accept your answer, it's easier to miss, etc.